# Space in between my code lines - JQuery and CSS

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

Here is the problem:

[image: spaces]

There is a space between the numbers and the actual code, here is my jQuery code:

```
$('pre').html('<table>'+$.map($('pre').text().split('\n'), function(t, i){
    return '<tr><td>'+(i+1)+'</td><td>'+t+'</td></tr>';
}).join('')+'</table>');
```

And here is my CSS code:

```
.contentBox {
    min-height: 500px;
    padding: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.5);
    border: 1px solid rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.5);
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

pre {
    background-color: #707070;
}

pre table {
    font-family : courier;
    padding: 2px;
}
pre table td:first-child {
    color:#ddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

And finally the HTML code:

```
<div class="contentBox">
    <div class="code">
        <pre>
            require_once('php_knowledge.php');
            require_once('java_knowledge.php');
        </pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

All help would be appreciated!

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @putvande how to remove the spaces

Answer (score 2):

The whitespaces inside `<pre>` are interpreted as text and transfered to the `<td>` cell (see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sWpzv/).

Avoid this by trimming the whitespaces: `return '<tr><td>'+(i+1)+'</td><td>'+t.trim()+'</td></tr>';` (http://jsfiddle.net/sWpzv/1/)

Comment: now the border by the numbers and the code lines are too close together, how would i space it out?